# \mathbbm{1} not working well with XeLaTeX/mathspec

Tags: fonts, mathspec, blackboard

it seems that `\mathbbm{1}` doesn't display with double lines when one changes to a different font using `mathspec` in XeLaTeX. For example, the MWE below uses Palatino, but I couldn't get it to work with any other font (Times New Roman, etc.).

The problem occurs when I try to specify that the math font be applied to numbers: `\setmathsfont(Digits){Palatino}` in the preamble. The `\mathbbm{1}` symbol displays correctly if you remove the `(Digits)`, but then numbers in a math environment don't match those in the text.

If this is a font issue, is there a way to change font temporarily in a math environment so that I could call something like `\LatinModern{ \mathbbm{1} }`?

As a separate but related issue, I don't even know how to include the Latin Modern (or whatever the default LaTeX font is) using XeLaTeX since it's not a font in my library.

Thanks for any help you can provide. MWE below.

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm, dsfont}
\RequirePackage{mathspec} 

\setmathsfont(Digits){Palatino} % causes problem

\begin{document}

This blackboard bold $\mathbbm{1}$ isn't double lined. 
Doublestroke package doesn't work either, $\mathds{1}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: With just `\usepackage{bbm}` and without `\RequirePackage{mathspec}` it works fine for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interaction of `mathspec` with font packages is not really predictable. You can fool the package with this trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{Palatino}
\setmathsfont(Digits){Palatino}

\newcommand{\mathbbm}[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{bbm}{m}{n}#1}} % from mathbbm.sty

\begin{document}

This blackboard bold $\mathbbm{1}$ is double lined.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The similar definition for `dsfont` would be

```
\newcommand{\mathds}[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{dsrom}{m}{n}#1}}
```

or with `dsss` instead of `dsrom` if the sans serif version is preferred.

A different approach would be to use `unicode-math` and the TG Pagella Math font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Palatino}
\setmathfont{TG Pagella Math}


\begin{document}

This blackboard bold $\mathbbm{1}$ is double lined.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks egreg! Can someone say a few words about how this works? What do the arguments of `\usefont{U}{bbm}{m}{n}{...}` do?

Comment: @HenryDeith Since `mathspec` has to do some magic with the interpretation of numbers in math formulas, I simply tell that `\mathbbm` is *not* a math formula and use the character 1 as found in the font used by the `bbm` package (encoding "U", family "bbm", medium weight "m" and normal shape "n").