# Mathds does not work in Dissertate template

Tags: symbols, templates

I am using the Dissertate template for my thesis, see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv).

In some math formulas I would like to use double-stroke ones. Usually, I'm using the dsfont and

```
$\mathds{1}$
```

to create this. However, using this template, this only creates a plain 1. I tried other packages too (mathbb, etc.), however nothing works. It does also not generate any error message, it just does not show what I expected to see.

How could I generate such an object in the environment of this template?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered contacting Overleaf's helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff  is top-notch.

Comment: Or maybe you could ask the developer himself at GitHub. He has the best knowledge of his code.

Comment: The problem is with the thesis class definition. The class uses `mathspec` and defines a specific font for the mathematics environments. Mainly, in line 78 of the Dissertate.cls the command `\setmathsfont` defines the font to be used with digits. Check this answer it might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88746/90297

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\mathbbm{1} not working well with XeLaTeX/mathspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88734/mathbbm1-not-working-well-with-xelatex-mathspec)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this also does not work. I'll ask the helpdesk @ Overleaf. If I find an answer, I'll post it.